# (General) How do I make my clients connect with TCP over Internet without port forwarding?

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm dealing with school programming projects that involve TCP connections over the Internet. I CANNOT use port forwarding on the clients! Having a relay server works. For example, instead of client A connecting to client B and sending data, they both connect to the server that has ports open to the WAN, and A sends data to the server, which sends it to B. However, this costs extra trips and complicates the process.

In general, how am I supposed to do this? Is there some trick to get clients to communicate directly, or is it necessary to have a relay server? I thought iChat did audio/video chats directly between clients, but no port forwarding or NAT-PMP/UPnP is involved, it seems.

In case it matters, I'm using Objective-C for this project and used Java for the last one, both running on Macs.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite broad, but in general your application has to know the address of the peer to be able to connect to it. If there's a router doing NAT or a firewall in between, that complicates things quite a lot (nowadays that is the case almost everywhere - from a security perspective, it's usually a good thing your PC can't be reached by others outside of your network).

So the first step is to figure out where to connect to. If the peer that needs to be connected to is not behind a firewall or NAT, then you can assign a DNS record to it, and then you can reach it via a hostname. DNS records can have low time to live values, so that dynamic addresses are not a problem. You can also use a server that acts as a registry: your clients register their current address with it, and can also query currently registered client addresses.

If one of the peers is behind NAT/packet filter firewall, then you can still connect from that device to the other one not being restricted that way.

If both devices are restricted, or you want to be able to initiate the connection from either one of them, then you need something like you mentioned, an interim server, or you have to "punch" the firewall or ask your router to forward incoming connections to your device. NAT-PMP or UPnP does this.

There are more advanced techniques as well.

I assume you use IPv4. IPv6 does not have the problem of NAT, but firewalls are still commonly used for IPv6 too.